# SQL Promotion and Rules table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to set some dynamic promotions (managed in admin-area) for an e-commerce-shop.

For example: if the client has a baseball-cap AND a baseball mask in the cart AND the cart-sum is greater than 100 $ offer him 20$ discount

I have following table-structure (can be changed):

```
PROMOTIONS (id, discount)
PROMOTIONS_RULES (id, promotions_id, variable, operator, value)
```

I've filled the table with following dummy-data:

```
PROMOTIONS
1, 20$

PROMOTIONS_RULES
1, 1, product_id, =, 2
1, 1, product_id, =, 3
1, 1, cart_sum, >, 100
```

My question is: how can I efficiently look for the right promotion for a specific cart-combination?

I have an array of product IDs and the cart sum. And I need to get the right promotional discount.

Thx for help guys!

Comment: can you give us your current code to give you a better help ?

Comment: there is no code actually. i‘m thinking about how to solve this in a query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really an direct answer to your question, but i would probably go with bundling the products themselves and discount their total value in the bundle's price.

Edit:

Made a little sketch that might help or lead you to some direction.

```
//table structure something like this
discounts
id_discount, amount, name

discount_rules 
id_rule, id_discount, combination (bool), min_cart_total_value, active (bool)

discount_combination
id_combination, id_rule

discount_combination_products
id_combination, id_product

// query for combination discounts when in shopping cart
Select d.id_discount
From discounts d
Left Join discount_rules dr on d.id_discount = dr.id_discount
Where dr.active = 1, dr.combination = 1

//sort the cart products
sort($cartproducts);

foreach($queried_ids as $discount_id){
//query for products in those combination discounts
Select dcp.id_product
From discount_rules dr
Left Join discount_combination dc on dr.id_rule = dc.id_rule
Left Join discount_combination_products dcp on dc.id_combination = dcp.id_combination
Where dr.id_discount = $discount_id

//match the cart with possible discounts
sort($result_array);
if($cartproducts == $result_array){
//match apply this discount to the cart and so on.
}
}
```

Also suggest you to check for existing E-commerce platforms and see how they've done it.

Comment: well, if someone orders 2 baseball caps (so the amount will be over a specific value) we may want to give him 25$ discount instead (only for example) the idea with the bundles was the first one. But we would like to have a tool for managing also discounts with more rules. That‘s because we don‘t want to work with static bundles.

Comment: Edited my answer, hope the sketch helps in your thought process.

Comment: thank you very much, it helped me a lot.. I've solved this via php. It seems like it's not possible to query the promotion in pure mysql.